# How to populate json object in UI Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using Angular 2 in my project,and I have this json object:

```
[
  {
    "city": "toto"
  },
  {
    "city": "titi"
  },
  {
    "city": "tata"
  },
  ...
]
```

What I want is, to populate this object in the UI like this:

> toto -> titi (with a button here)
>   titi -> tata (with a button here)

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
<div formArrayName="prices">
  <div *ngFor="let myGroup of myForm.controls.prices.controls; let i=index">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <span *ngIf="myForm.controls.prices.controls.length > 1" >
      </span>
    <div class="input-group spinner">
    <input type="text" formControlName="price" class="form-control" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: please add more info the variables used here in the template and as well of the json object you have shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index">
    <span>{{item.city}}</span> --> <span *ngIf="items[i+1]">{{items[i+1].city}}</span>
</div>
```

outputs:

> toto --> titi
>
> titi --> tata
>
> tata -->

If you want to not show the last item use `let last = last` and filter out the last item.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index; let last = last">
  <div *ngIf="!last">
    <span>{{item.city}}</span> --> <span *ngIf="items[i+1]">{{items[i+1].city}}</span>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer but the for loop should stop in titi-->tata how to make it stop

Comment: You can use `let last = last` in your `*ngFor` and add a condition to not display the last item. I'll update my answer.